# Protocol Composition for Dependency Injection - Causality Dilemma / Compile Issue

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, protocols

I am trying to use Swift "Protocol Composition" for dependency injection for the first time.  There are various blog posts from well respected engineers in the field advocating this approach but I am unable to get the  code to compile once there are dependencies that depend upon other dependencies.

The problem is that until your main concrete `AllDependencies` instance is initialised it cannot be used to initialise the child dependencies, but conversely you cannot create the child dependencies without the concrete `AllDependencies` instance.

Chicken & egg. Rock and hard place.

I'll try and provide the simplest example I can...

```
protocol HasAppInfo {
    var appInfo: AppInfoProtocol { get }
}
protocol AppInfoProtocol {
    var apiKey: String { get }
}
struct AppInfo: AppInfoProtocol {
    let apiKey: String
}

protocol HasNetworking {
    var networking: NetworkingProtocol { get }
}
protocol NetworkingProtocol {
    func makeRequest()
}
class Networking: NetworkingProtocol {

    typealias Dependencies = HasAppInfo

    let dependencies: Dependencies

    init(dependencies: Dependencies) {
        self.dependencies = dependencies
    }

    func makeRequest() {
        let apiKey = self.dependencies.appInfo.apiKey
        // perform request sending API Key
        // ...
    }
}

class AllDependencies: HasAppInfo, HasNetworking {

    let appInfo: AppInfoProtocol
    let networking: NetworkingProtocol

    init() {
        self.appInfo = AppInfo(apiKey: "whatever")

        /// **********************************************************
        /// *** ERROR: Constant 'self.networking' used before being initialized
        /// **********************************************************
        self.networking = Networking(dependencies: self)
    }

}
```

It seems like it might be possible to resolve this with use of `lazy var`, `{get set}` or `mutating` dependencies but that seems extermely unsafe because any code in your system can mutate your dependencies at will.

Would appreciate understanding how others have resolved what seems like a pretty fundamental issue with this approach.

**References**

- http://merowing.info/2017/04/using-protocol-compositon-for-dependency-injection/
- https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/03/06/dependency-injection-in-swift-with-protocols/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a private(set) lazy var:

```swift
private(set) lazy var networking: NetworkingProtocol = {
    return Networking(dependencies: self)
}()
```

Comment: Answer accepted.  Thanks Mike!  I did actually try this before posting but it didn't work at that time because I had `AllDependencies` defined as a `struct`!!!! If it's a `class` then its all good.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*PS: I posted the original question.* I have already accepted the `lazy var` answer, this is the simplest way forward, however I wanted to post this alternative solution that uses a generic `DependencyFactory` in case it helps others.

```
protocol Dependencies:
    HasAppInfo &
    HasNetworking
{}


class DependencyFactory {

    typealias Factory<T> = (Dependencies) -> T

    private enum DependencyState<T> {
        case registered(Factory<T>)
        case initialised(T)
    }

    private var dependencyStates = [String: Any]()

    func register<T>(_ type: T.Type, factory: @escaping Factory<T>) {
        dependencyStates[key(for: type)] = DependencyState<T>.registered(factory)
    }

    func unregister<T>(_ type: T.Type) {
        dependencyStates[key(for: type)] = nil
    }

    func resolve<T>(_ type: T.Type, dependencies: Dependencies) -> T {
        let key = self.key(for: type)

        guard let dependencyState = dependencyStates[key] as? DependencyState<T> else {
            fatalError("Attempt to access unregistered `\(type)` dependency")
        }

        switch dependencyState {

        case let .registered(factoryClosure):
            let dependency = factoryClosure(dependencies)
            dependencyStates[key] = DependencyState<T>.initialised(dependency)
            return dependency

        case let .initialised(dependency):
            return dependency

        }
    }

    private func key<T>(for type: T.Type) -> String {
        return String(reflecting: type)
    }
}


class AllDependencies: Dependencies {

    private let dependencyFactory = DependencyFactory()

    init() {
        dependencyFactory.register(AppInfoProtocol.self, factory: { dependencies in
            return AppInfo(apiKey: "whatever")
        })

        dependencyFactory.register(NetworkingProtocol.self, factory: { dependencies in
            return Networking(dependencies: dependencies)
        })
    }

    var appInfo: AppInfo {
        return dependencyFactory.resolve(AppInfoProtocol.self, dependencies: self)
    }

    var networking: Networking {
        return dependencyFactory.resolve(NetworkingProtocol.self, dependencies: self)
    }
}
```